# Laravel 5.0 Cartalyst Sentinel Setup

Tags: php, laravel, cartalyst-sentinel

I'm trying to install Sentinel into my Laravel 5.0 application, however despite following the guide to the letter:

https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0#laravel-5

I keep getting the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Class 'Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\SentinelServiceProvider::class' not found
```

I have this in the config\app.php

Providers Array:

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\BusServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider',

    'Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\SentinelServiceProvider::class',
],
```

Aliases Array:

```
'aliases' => [

    'App'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
    'Artisan'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan',
    'Auth'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth',
    'Blade'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade',
    'Bus'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus',
    'Cache'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache',
    'Config'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config',
    'Cookie'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie',
    'Crypt'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt',
    'DB'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB',
    'Eloquent'  => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
    'Event'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event',
    'File'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\File',
    'Hash'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash',
    'Input'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input',
    'Inspiring' => 'Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring',
    'Lang'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang',
    'Log'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log',
    'Mail'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail',
    'Password'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password',
    'Queue'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue',
    'Redirect'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect',
    'Redis'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis',
    'Request'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request',
    'Response'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response',
    'Route'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route',
    'Schema'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema',
    'Session'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session',
    'Storage'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage',
    'URL'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL',
    'Validator' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator',
    'View'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\View',

    'Activation'=> 'Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Activation::class',
    'Reminder'  => 'Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Reminder::class',
    'Sentinel'  => 'Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel::class',
],
```

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong? Ive been messing with it for a while now, trying different file paths including an absolute one but I get the same result every time :(

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i believe I've figured it out, I needed to remove the ::class suffix from the config.

However not having completed the process, my sessions still do not need to be inserted into the database, I think I must be doing something wrong again :(

Regards,